# How to always keep exactly one element with active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Im trying to rewrite this in a simpler and cleaner way using jQuery each()

```
$imageContainer = $('#indicator-color').children()
  for e, idx in $imageContainer
    e = $(e)
    if idx is currentIdx
      e.addClass('active')
    else
      e.removeClass('active')
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
$('#indicator-color').children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', index == currentIdx);
});
```

With CoffeeScript:

```
$("#indicator-color").children().each (index) ->
  $(this).toggleClass "active", index is currentIdx
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this

```
$('#indicator-color').children().removeClass('active').eq(currentIdx).addClass('active');
```